# Typo in Markdown Help

Tags: discussion, markdown, formatting

The first sample code paragraph for [Basic Links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#basic-links) at Markdown Help seems a bit messed up, with the links within the sentence being in the wrong order, and may not very helpful for a puzzled reader seeking help!

I reckon it should read like this, shouldn't it?

```
Here's an inline link to [Google](http://www.google.com/).
```

Same problem with the following two lines.

Comment: From the question on meta.se linked to by @Werner: the issue is resolved network-wide since yesterday (May 1st 2020).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed. This seems like a markdown "typo." However, it is a network-wide issue and should therefore be addressed at that level. There is a similar question related to this posted on the main network meta: [Markdown help page is broken (badly presented/formatted) on every site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347211/168244).